# Cannot seem to load datagrid wpf Can you help?

Tags: wpf

For some reasons I cannot seem to populate a datagrid I get the following error:

***System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Customers' property not found on 'object' ''ObservableCollection`1' (HashCode=11497055)***

Can you spot what I am doing wrong?

The code is as follows:

```
    ViewModel
    =============
        public class CustomerVM : ViewModelBase
        {
            private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers;          
            public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
            {
                get { return _customers; }
                set
                {
                    _customers = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Customers");
                }
            }   

            private DelegateCommand _getCustomersCommand;
            public ICommand GetCustomersCommand
            {
                get
                {
                    return _getCustomersCommand ?? (_getCustomersCommand = new DelegateCommand(x => GetCustomers(), x => CanGetCustomer));
                }
            }
            private static bool CanGetCustomer
            {
                get { return true; }
            }
            private void GetCustomers()
            {
                Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>
                           {
                               new Customer{Id=1,Name ="Jo",Surname = "Bloggs",IsMember = true},
                               new Customer{Id=2,Name ="Mark", Surname = "Cole",IsMember = false},
                               new Customer{Id=3,Name ="Robert ", Surname = "Smith",IsMember = true},
                               new Customer{Id=4,Name ="Vincent", Surname = "Varc",IsMember = false},
                           };
            }
        }    


          Customer Wpf Window
          ====================
          <Window x:Class="Sample.CustomerDataGridSample"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
            Title="CustomerDataGridSample" Height="300" Width="300" Loaded="OnWindowsLoaded" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Customers"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       FontSize="12"/>
            <toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="dg" Grid.Row="1"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"                            
                               CanUserAddRows="False" 
                               CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                               CanUserResizeRows="False" 
                               CanUserSortColumns="False"
                               AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                               RowHeaderWidth="17" RowHeight="25">
                <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn   Header="Name"
                                              Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn   Header="Surname"
                                              Binding="{Binding Path=Surname}" />
                    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn   Header="Is Member"
                                              Binding="{Binding Path=IsMember}" />
                </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            </toolkit:DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Window>

     public partial class CustomerDataGridSample:Window
    {
        public CustomerDataGridSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void OnWindowsLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var customerVm = new CustomerVM();
            customerVm.GetCustomersCommand.Execute(null);
            DataContext = customerVm.Customers;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message alone gives it away - your binding has the wrong context.

You're setting the `DataContext` of your window to `customerVm.Customers` in the loaded method.  That means that your bindings "start" from the `Customers` property already, and so the binding on your grid is actually trying to find `customerVm.Customers.Customers`.  That's why you get the error message you do: an `ObservableCollection` has no `Customers` property.

You can either change it so the `DataContext` set in code is simply `customerVm`, or use `ItemsSource={Binding}` on the DataGrid (which will then just pick up the current `DataContext`).

Comment: The error message did give it away but could not see what I was doing wrong.Thanks that fixed!!!!